# Rainfall based Crop Insurance Payout calculation

Tags: python, weather

I am analysing daily rainfall data to calculate Insurance payout for farmers in case of excess rainfall coverage. policy covers if the "Consecutive 3 day cumulative rainfall" is greater than 50mm between 1st-Oct and 31st-Oct.

I was able to write the code in Python to find the matching criteria. But when it rains continuously then the result has overlapping dates which is not acceptable payout.

Need help in calculating best payout option in case of overlapping dates.

```
for dist in data["dcode"].unique():
    d_data = data[data["dcode"] == dist]
    #print(dist)
    for block in d_data["mandal"].unique():
        prev_rain = 0
        prev_to_date = "01/12/2022"
        for each in rain_dev_input:
            #[(rain_dev_input["TERM"] == "DEFICIT RAINFALL") & (rain_dev_input["DIST_CODE"] == 240)]:
            #print(each)
            distcode = each["DIST_CODE"]
            #print(distcode)
            term = str(each["TERM"])
            if (distcode == dist) & (term == "EXCESS RAINFALL"):
                start_date = each["FROM_PERIOD"]
                end_date = each["TO_PERIOD"]
                s_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%y")
                e_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%d/%m/%y")
                #s_date = start_date.strftime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
                #e_date = end_date.strftime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
                #count1 = daterange(s_date, e_date)
                #print(s_date, ": ", e_date)

                m_data = d_data[d_data["mandal"] == block]
                p_data = m_data.loc[start_date:end_date]
                for singledate in daterange(s_date, e_date):
                    #print("Inside Excess Rain")
                    from_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(singledate, "%Y-%m-%d")
                    to_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(
                        (singledate + timedelta(2)), "%Y-%m-%d"
                    )
                    total_rain = p_data.loc[from_date:to_date]["rain"].sum()
                    #print(total_rain)
                    range1 = float(each["RANGE1"])
                    range2 = float(each["RANGE2"])

                    if (total_rain >= range1) & (total_rain < range2):
                        #print("inside write to file")
                        if (from_date <= prev_to_date <= to_date) & (prev_rain <= total_rain):
                            temp["Max"] = total_rain;

                        prev_rain = total_rain
                        prev_to_date = to_date
                        temp = dict()
                        temp["district"] = each["DIST_NAME"]
                        temp["mandal"] = block
                        temp[
                            "category"
                        ] = "excess rainfall for 3 consecutive days, cumulative"
                        temp["rainfall"] = total_rain
                        temp["from_date"] = from_date
                        temp["to_date"] = to_date
                        temp["phase"] = each["PHASE"]
                        #temp["insurance"] = insurance_excessrain(each, total_rain)
                        temp["insurance"] = (total_rain - range1)* each["PAYOUT"]
                        excess_rainfall.append(temp)
# %%
# output excess rainfall rain_dev_list data
excess_rain = pd.DataFrame(excess_rainfall)
excess_rain.to_csv(str(output_folder) + "/excess_rainfall_2020_h2.csv", index=False)
```

### This result has overlapping dates

[image: this result has overlapping dates]

### Daily Rainfall sample data

[image: Daily Rainfall sample data]

Comment: Where is the raw data?

Comment: I asked a friend. He replied: Haha, interesting indeed. The error is because you have to calculate deficit or excess rainfall using the normal rainfall during that period as the base. Not the cumulative of that month.

Comment: There are different ways you can treat this. 1. You can check out if the criteria is fullfilled for every day. In this case I recommend to use a rolling sum . Another way could be to count handle each rain period as an event. For this you hav to add a new column with event numbers for each rain period and summarize over these periods.